# Cronjob is not executing at scheduled interval

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have kubernetes cronjob at defined interval. This needs to be run for every 5hours 15mins. But might be issue with cron scheduled.

This is my kubernetes CronJob :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: Cronjob-monitor
  namespace: cronjobs
  labels:
    app: Cronjob-monitor
spec:
  schedule: "15 5 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            agentpool: streaming
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

This is not executing for every 5hrs 15th min. Can any one guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed that you have given cron job schedule syntax as  : "15 5 * * *" . This will run everyday 5th hr 15 min but not as per your requirement . So, Seems to be a cron job schedule syntax issue. Can you try by giving this syntax `15 */5 * * 1-7` . As per the below screenshot, this cron job syntax will run for every 5 hr's 15th min from monday to sunday.

[image]

You can use this [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) play tool to check the syntax of the scheduled job according to our requirements. Can you try the above suggested syntax and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Crontab play tool helped me verify and above syntax is working fine. I missed to take step at Hourth place and this also working as expected 15 */5 * * *